# Problems with Ubuntu permissions when changing the Disk Home directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I've changed the home directory of hard drive, because I don't have any more space,but from that point I have millions of problems with permissions for snap installations, the printer and a long list of things.

I have also used the command `chown`:

```
chown -R carlos:carlos /home/carlos
```

but it seems that when I do an operation, the permits are changed again.

I put my file /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=b575130c-95e1-4552-980a-ee6734ea9726 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=6ffc8c65-9c4b-4af1-8224-0f09f185923e none            swap    sw              0       0
# cdrom 0
# cdrom 1
UUID=2C4C3DA84C3D6E28   /home   ntfs   defaults   0   2
```

Comment: NTFS doesn't support Linux permissions etc., I think.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski: The NTFS device is not a HDD; it's an optical ('cdrom 1').

Comment: Same as above... Usually the real space-eaters are well below `/home`: videos, music, photo... A solution is to keep /home in the ext4 fs, and put these big directories on the NTFS filesystem and soft-link them into the user directories in `/home` for convenience.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answer. I had no idea about NTFS.
The problem is that many of the files with the extension ".", occupy a lot of space, example: Node, Composer, .config, home/www so there is no other solution, right? Will I have to buy another disk with more space?